# Wordpress MySQL: add new term relationships if term_taxonomy_id == 4

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I need to find rows with `term_taxonomy_id == 4` and add new term relationships, kind of like that: 
http://picpaste.com/28dbd65ee0-hRbWftsI.jpg

On the screenshot the post with `object_id == 2108` has term relationships 57, 60, 62 and 64 — and I need an every post linked with `term_taxonomy_id == 4` has the same relationships too... I haven't worked with SQL much, so I got stuck with that. Which SQL commands should I use (except `INSERT INTO wp_term_relationships`, I got it).

http://picpaste.com/28dbd65ee0-hRbWftsI.jpg

Comment: If it is only SQL i would use LEFT JOIN for the selects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did it myself:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table AS SELECT *
FROM wp_term_relationships
WHERE term_taxonomy_id = '4';
UPDATE temp_table SET term_taxonomy_id = '58' WHERE term_taxonomy_id = '4';
INSERT INTO wp_term_relationships
SELECT *
FROM temp_table;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table;
```